# Javascript not returning style properties

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple script that is getting the color of the text in an element and printing it to the console.  However, when I run the script, I'm getting an empty string rather than the actual color.  Can anyone explain to me why and how to fix it?

**HTML**

```
<div id="scrollingTextHolder">
    <p id="scrollingText">Hello</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#scrollingText{
    margin-top: 5%;
    color: black;
}
```

**JS**

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    console.log(document.getElementById("scrollingText").style.color);
})
```

[Pen](http://codepen.io/RobbyT15/pen/xVMLdO)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `getComputedStyle()` and `getPropertyValue()`, also color is returned as `rgb(R,G,B)`

```js
var a = document.getElementById("scrollingText");
console.log(window.getComputedStyle(a).getPropertyValue('color'))
```

```css
#scrollingText {
  margin-top: 5%;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="scrollingTextHolder">
  <p id="scrollingText">Hello</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you for actually providing help instead of just giving a link to a similar question that doesn't actually provide any help.

Comment: `:)` you're welcome.